# Can you get two identical order_position (or row number) in DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, common-table-expression

My question: under which circumstance/condition would my code below would return two identical rows, both with ORDER_POSITION=1.

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce my issue, but earlier I was working on a production issue in which my query was returning duplicates. That is two identical records with ORDER_POSITION=1 for both. How would this be possible? Even if all columns are identical, should this not return two identical rows with different order positions? (row numbers)?

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT A.Name, 
       A.Device,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, A.ORDERDATE, 120) AS ORDER_DATE,  
       ORDER_TIME,
       A.ORDER_BDATE,
       A.ORDER_BTIME,
       Product,
       A.PR_ID
FROM MyTable A
WHERE 
      A.Product = 'GPS' AND
      A.[STATUS] ='ACTIVE'
  )

SELECT R.*
FROM (
SELECT A.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Name ORDER BY A.ORDER_DATE DESC, A.ORDER_TIME DESC) AS ORDER_POSITION
FROM CTE A) R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two rows have same `a.name`, `A.ORDER_DATE` and `A.ORDER_TIME` then `dense_rank` will give same number to them.

`Dense_rank` groups the rows using the columns mentioned in the `partition by` clause and trys to give the numbers to the rows using columns in the `order by` clause. But if two rows in the same group have the same values in the columns used in the `order by` clause, it gives same the number to them.

If you want different numbers for them then use `row_number` instead of `dense_rank`.

Answer (score 1):

`DENSE_RANK()`  will return the same value if, to use your example, multiple records with the same value for `ORDER_DATE` and `ORDER_TIME` within same `A.Name`

You probably wanna use `ROW_NUMBER()` to produce unique number for duplicate cases